# how would i use a for loop in my makefile to redirect my output?

Tags: java, makefile, output-redirect

```
run: $(CLASSES)
     for number in 2 4 6 8 10 12; do \
        $(JAVA) -cp $(BINDIR) Shuffled $$number ; \
     done
```

in this part of my makefile I run my class 6 times using a swap method of randomising, now my question is, would it be possible to redirect my output into a text file for each run and how would I go about doing this (can we use a for loop to redirect output for each run?)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the code of the `Shuffled.java` class, you can just... send all output to a file instead of system.out. Alternatively, just.. use a redirect:

```
$(JAVA) -cp $(BINDIR) Shuffled $$number >$$number.txt ; \
```

should produce files `2.txt`, `6.txt`, etcetera.